# 100% Height Not Working On Browser Resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fluid-layout

I'm building an alternative to fullPage.js which will fit my needs better, but I'm having some issues getting the sections to stay at 100% height when the browser is being resized.

I have 5 sections that should all be `height: 100%, width: 100%` at all times. You should only be able to get one section in your browser viewport at a time. I did this using anchors attached to each section `id`. Then the `body` has `overflow: hidden` to prevent vertical scrolling. The sections each contain images that should also take up `height: 100%` with the `width` being determined automatically to keep aspect ration of images.

This solution works when I first load the page, but as soon as the browser starts being resized, other sections become visible, and the `img`'s that have a `height: 100%` become much smaller than the full browser height. Is this is a limitation to CSS, or am I doing something wrong?

Is there a javascript solution to detect browsers viewport, and apply those `height` and `width` values to a series of `id`'?

Here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/mtthwbckmn/pen/BKjJw).

Answer (score 1):

add this to your `HEAD` section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

then in your CSS:

```
html, body{
  height:100%;
}
@-ms-viewport{
  width: device-width;
}
```

Additionally, I'd suggest to use vh (viewport height) and vw (viewport width). [Read more here](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/)

Comment: I've made the changes you've mentioned. I added the `<meta>` into the `<head>` and added the CSS. I also changed the section containers to use vh & vw values instead of percentages. If you see my updated codepen, only the first section works as you'd expect. The sections below the first (`#people`) all become messed up again when you resize. See updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/mtthwbckmn/pen/BKjJw).

Comment: Safari & Chrome. You have to click one of the bottom 3 links to the left, then resize the codepen height. It will break and show both the row above and below. Once you click the link to the left again, it will reinterpret the values again and make it look normal, but once again, if you resize the codepen it breaks.

Comment: in your code for `#people, #places, #things, #food` change `height: 100vh;` to `min-height: 100vh;`

Comment: That makes things much worse. Updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/mtthwbckmn/pen/BKjJw). It worked better when the `height: 100vh` was in place instead of the `min-height: 100vh`. Can you get it working on your end? If so fork it and send me that link so I can take a look at what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you clicking one of the bottom three links and resizing both up and down in codepen? Your codepen doesn't work in Chrome, Safari, Opera or Firefox.

Comment: weird. When I posted was working and now it isn't. Then really don't know, I'm off to sleep but will take a look tomorrow, or maybe someone else can find what is going on